# NSOperation dealloc not being called when added as dependency of another NSOperation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsoperation

Using Instrument I've seen that a lot of my custom NSOperation are never deallocated. I've put a breakpoint in the dealloc method and it is never called.

I've also noticed that the problem occurs when I add any NSOperation as a dependency of another NSOperation. If I remove the following sentence from my code, the dealloc method of myOperation is called.

```
[otherOperation addDependency:myOperation];
```

Comment: Are you releasing otherOperation somewhere in your code?  If you want to keep otherOperation around but release myOperation you would want to use '[otherOperation removeDependency:myOperation];'.

Comment: I have a bunch of NSOperation (maybe 30k) and one operation that is executed at the last place, so, I add every NSOperation I create as a dependency of that final operation. The problem is that since there are a lot of operation and this last operation is executed at the end, the other operations are not being deallocated (at least until the last operation is executed).

Comment: It's not a matter of your code not being called, it's that NSOperations do not have an exception handler, and cannot be stopped by the debugger.